# What are some things you can own that generate income?

Tags: income

If you rent a four bedroom apartment, you can earn income renting out each of the rooms. What are some other things that you can buy for a relatively low cost from which one can earn income?

Comment: Can you narrow your question or describe things you've alread thought about? The whole thing of "making profit" is based on buying cheap and selling higher. For ones those are cat whiskers for others gold mines.

Comment: Where can I find the cat whiskers market??

Comment: If you are a good enough salesman, you can probably convince someone to rent a pencil from you.

Answer (score 1):

Dividend producing stocks, funds or ETFs.
CDs
Bonds
Blog Posts with affiliate links
Monetized YouTube videos.

Comment: Designer clothing. Slaves. Prize stallions (for sperm!).

Comment: Some of those are not low cost (or legal)

Comment: OP didn't say they had to be legal! :-p